# Google Maps rotate marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to rotate a Google Maps Marker. I'm using the JavaScript v3 API. What is the best way of doing this? I've had a look at some other similar questions but there seems to be no clear answer, or if there is it's for v2.

I'm looking for a neat/tidy way to rotate the marker icon.

**Edit:**

As this question has started to rise in views quite dramatically I have decided to edit it to make the result of my question clearer.

## You can't

Answer (score 0):

A marker image cant be rotated.. you will need to create new images of all your possible rotations and replace the marker image as required with a rotate image file.. using marker.setIcon()

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to animate the rotation doing it this way?

Comment: Yes.. but only by changing the marker image in quick succession with new marker images to achieve the effect of animation..

Comment: I think its the good answer...y '-1' is given...However even this may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800613/rotating-image-marker-image-on-google-map-v3

Answer (score -3):

How about? chart-API

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.25|38|FF0000|12|text-1|text-2

It rotates a red spin marker by 38degree scaled 25%,and labeled with two lines texts.

Comment: It gives error in argument.

Comment: Please correct the URL.