# Google Map Custom image icon rotation

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I am trying to draw arrow images on the google map and rotate them according to the certain angle.I dont wanna use google predefined Icons.

Here is my code which I was trying but it is not working.Image is coming but unable to rotate image.

```
degreeRotation = 90 ;
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : position,
                map : map,
                icon :{ 
                    url: '../resources/images/arrow.png',
                    scale: 1,
                    rotation: degreeRotation,   
                    },
            });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: rotation is only available for SVG-icons(Symbols)

Comment: POssible copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800613/rotating-image-marker-image-on-google-map-v3