# JS - canvas.toDataURL Fails

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-maps-api-3

I've been working with some google maps recently, and I needed to rotate the icon for a map marker.  I did some research, and came across [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800613/rotating-image-marker-image-on-google-map-v3#answer-29411992).

Unfortunately, it's not working properly.  It won't render the image I need.  The URL produced by canvas.toDataURL is a blank image (of the correct size).

Here is the code:

```
var latlong0=new google.maps.LatLng(44.422036688671, -73.857908744819);    function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 44.422036688671, lng: -73.857908744819},
    zoom: 0
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  var airplane = 'img/airplane_icon.png';

  var infowindow0=new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: `
      <div>
        <p class='spectxt'>&lt;Flight #&gt;</p>
    <div style='font-size:10px;'>
          <p class='gentxtl'>Airline: <span class='acptxt'>Aero Test Ltd</span></p>
      <p class='gentxtl'>Aircraft: <span class='acptxt'>Boeing 717-200 HGW</span></p>
      <p class='gentxtl'>From: <span class='acptxt'>YYZ</span></p>
      <p class='gentxtl'>To: <span class='acptxt'>YHZ</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
    });

  var mark0=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlong0,
    map: map,
    title:'Aircraft',
    icon: {
            url: RotateIcon
                .makeIcon(
                    '/img/airplane_icon.png')
                .setRotation({deg: 78})
                .getUrl()
        }
  });
  mark0.setMap(map);mark0.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow0.open(map, mark0);
    });    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The RotateIcon code:

```
  var RotateIcon = function(options){
    this.options = options || {};
    this.rImg = options.img || new Image();
    this.rImg.src = this.rImg.src || this.options.url || '';
    this.options.width = this.options.width || this.rImg.width || 50;
    this.options.height = this.options.height || this.rImg.height || 50;
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.options.width;
    canvas.height = this.options.height;
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.canvas = canvas;
};
RotateIcon.makeIcon = function(url) {
    return new RotateIcon({url: url});
};
RotateIcon.prototype.setRotation = function(options){
    var canvas = this.context,
        angle = options.deg ? options.deg * Math.PI / 180:
            options.rad,
        centerX = this.options.width/2,
        centerY = this.options.height/2;

    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, this.options.width, this.options.height);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(centerX, centerY);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
    canvas.drawImage(this.rImg, 0, 0);
    canvas.restore();
    return this;
};
RotateIcon.prototype.getUrl = function(){
    return this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};
```

The image is on the same domain as the web page, and both resources are regular http (no https).  Chrome DevTools reports no warnings or errors.  canvas.toDataURL outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/b9GHwgzt)

I'm using Chrome 48 on Windows 8.1

I've noticed something else odd with it.  If I change the URL to `/img/logo.png`, it creates the image I want, but with the wrong sizing.  canvas.toDataURL outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/ZBMZT3ud)

-EDIT-
`/img/airplane_icon.png` can be found [here](http://flyhighsim.cf/img/airplane_icon.png)
`/img/logo.png` can be found [here](http://flyhighsim.cf/img/logo.png)

-EDIT 2-
So, I made a [test page](http://flyhighsim.cf/map_test.html), and found it working....  So I went back to my first page, and noticed that if I have `<img src="/img/airplane_icon.png">` after the map canvas, the page will work, but if I remove it, the page will not.  Strange.  For now I'm just going to add a `display:none` to the img, but does anyone know why the img has to be included for the page to work?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including a copy of the icon you are using.  If I take an airplane icon from the web, your code seems to work correctly for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wgh6ko6t/3/)).

Comment: I get a 404 for the airplane...

Comment: Fixed.  Of course I used the wrong link in the edit.  The code itself uses the correct link.

Comment: [Your code as posted works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_rotatePNGicon_orig.html). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: There are issues in IE (surprize, surprize...), but they are invalid character (`) and unterminated string constant, which can be addressed.

Comment: Seems like a problem with the asynchronous load of the image if it is not already available in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a problem with the asynchronous load of the image if it is not already available in the cache.  One option to address that is to load the icon as a data URI:

```
var airplaneIcon = new RotateIcon({
  url: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyAgMAAABjUWAiAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABh0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMC41ZYUyZQAAAAlQTFRF////AH8OAH8OqhPhTgAAAAJ0Uk5TADqwnxSKAAAAZ0lEQVQoz2NgoCJQQOYwrkTmMa0aijy2VQ5IvKxVS5ClViFJZgF5S5ClEJJZYN4SZCmYpBaUtwDGm7RKCsGbAHSLFIw3AewyqQUD5XepVRNwhQTjqlUrcYULF5DXgOAtYchqoF5yAwBuvj9B9E9ozgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
  height: 50,
  width: 50
})
var mark0 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlong0,
  map: map,
  title: 'Aircraft',
  icon: {
  // size: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
    url: airplaneIcon.setRotation({
        deg: 78
    })
    .getUrl()
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wgh6ko6t/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var RotateIcon = function(options) {
  this.options = options || {};
  this.rImg = options.img || new Image();
  this.rImg.src = this.rImg.src || this.options.url || '';
  this.options.width = this.options.width || this.rImg.width || 50;
  this.options.height = this.options.height || this.rImg.height || 50;
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = this.options.width;
  canvas.height = this.options.height;
  this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.canvas = canvas;
};
RotateIcon.makeIcon = function(url) {
  return new RotateIcon({
    url: url
  });
};
RotateIcon.prototype.setRotation = function(options) {
  var canvas = this.context,
    angle = options.deg ? options.deg * Math.PI / 180 :
    options.rad,
    centerX = this.options.width / 2,
    centerY = this.options.height / 2;

  canvas.clearRect(0, 0, this.options.width, this.options.height);
  canvas.save();
  canvas.translate(centerX, centerY);
  canvas.rotate(angle);
  canvas.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
  canvas.drawImage(this.rImg, 0, 0);
  canvas.restore();
  return this;
};
RotateIcon.prototype.getUrl = function() {
  return this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
};

var map;
var latlong0 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.422036688671, -73.857908744819);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 44.422036688671,
      lng: -73.857908744819
    },
    zoom: 5
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  var airplane = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyAgMAAABjUWAiAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABh0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMC41ZYUyZQAAAAlQTFRF////AH8OAH8OqhPhTgAAAAJ0Uk5TADqwnxSKAAAAZ0lEQVQoz2NgoCJQQOYwrkTmMa0aijy2VQ5IvKxVS5ClViFJZgF5S5ClEJJZYN4SZCmYpBaUtwDGm7RKCsGbAHSLFIw3AewyqQUD5XepVRNwhQTjqlUrcYULF5DXgOAtYchqoF5yAwBuvj9B9E9ozgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

  var infowindow0 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: `
      <div>
        <p class='spectxt'>&lt;Flight #&gt;</p>
    <div style='font-size:10px;'>
          <p class='gentxtl'>Airline: <span class='acptxt'>Aero Test Ltd</span></p>
      <p class='gentxtl'>Aircraft: <span class='acptxt'>Boeing 717-200 HGW</span></p>
      <p class='gentxtl'>From: <span class='acptxt'>YYZ</span></p>
      <p class='gentxtl'>To: <span class='acptxt'>YHZ</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      `
  });
  var airplaneIcon = new RotateIcon({
    url: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyAgMAAABjUWAiAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAABh0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMC41ZYUyZQAAAAlQTFRF////AH8OAH8OqhPhTgAAAAJ0Uk5TADqwnxSKAAAAZ0lEQVQoz2NgoCJQQOYwrkTmMa0aijy2VQ5IvKxVS5ClViFJZgF5S5ClEJJZYN4SZCmYpBaUtwDGm7RKCsGbAHSLFIw3AewyqQUD5XepVRNwhQTjqlUrcYULF5DXgOAtYchqoF5yAwBuvj9B9E9ozgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
    height: 50,
    width: 50
  })
  var mark0 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlong0,
    map: map,
    title: 'Aircraft',
    icon: {
      // size: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
      url: airplaneIcon.setRotation({
          deg: 78
        })
        .getUrl()
    }
  });
  mark0.setMap(map);
  mark0.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow0.open(map, mark0);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```