# Google map rotation

Tags: google-maps

I am unable to view the rotation icon when I create a google map setting the 
type id to satelite as shown below.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: 18,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
          heading: 0
    });
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: See the following answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800613/rotating-image-marker-image-on-google-map-v3

Comment: I tried that however it rotates all the individual images in the map. I dont want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification):

> **rotateControl** enables/disables the appearance of a Rotate control for
>   controlling the orientation of 45° imagery. By default, the control's
>   presence is determined by the presence or absence of 45° imagery for
>   the given map type at the current zoom and location. You may alter the
>   control's behavior by setting the map's rotateControlOptions to
>   specify the RotateControlOptions to use. **You cannot make the control
>   appear if no 45° imagery is currently available.**

Also, `rotateControl` appears only if zoom is high enough. For example, this `map` will not show `rotateControl`:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: -37.8136, lng: 144.9631},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });
}
```

But if you zoom it a bit more, it will show `rotateControl`:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: {lat: -37.8136, lng: 144.9631},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });
}
```

Comment: I have set the map type id to google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE and the zoom to 19. Yet I dont see the rotate control as I have mentioned in my example. Can you please tell me why

Comment: *You cannot make the control appear if no 45° imagery is currently available* - meaning, your code is fine, but google does not provide rotation feature on the `LatLng` that you are using. Try some large city `LatLng`, I am 99% sure it will work.

Comment: Which are the cities where this a available. I am currently trying all big cities in India but not getting the icon...

Comment: Part of the list is here (I have not managed to find anything more up to date): https://maps.googleblog.com/2012/11/imagery-update-tour-sites-around-world.html. New York and Melbourne works for sure. Looks like India is not available yet.

Comment: Is it possible to display the compass seen in earth view...do you have any idea about that ??