# Can I give an anchor to a marker in agm/core?

Tags: angular-google-maps

I created a marker with a custom image, but the image is anchored to the bottom of the image. I want to give the the centre if the image as the anchor point so that even if I rotate the image, it rotates around the centre.

I followed this excellent solution [Rotating image / marker image on Google map V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800613/rotating-image-marker-image-on-google-map-v3/29411992#29411992) to rotate the custom image on the marker in agm/core (angular 4).

thanks to @ErDmKo

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible by using the Object like in the official Google Maps Doc instead of the string like in the AGM Doc.

It works like:

```
<agm-marker [iconUrl]="{url: '/assets/icons/icon-map-home.png',  anchor : {x:19, y:19}}">
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer: works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the functionality existed in the @agm/core, but its not documented...

we can give like this in iconUrl (it is supposed to be icon )
 anchor : {x:25, y:25}

Comment: Can you describe this little more? 
Thanks in advance ;)