# How to move Agm map in angular and fixed marker to the center and update lat and lng?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular 9 application i am using `@agm/core` to display map and showing a marker on the map and maker is draggable but i want marker should fixed on center and map should be moveable when map move stoped then update lat and lng how can i do this in angular. thanks in advance.

[this is my project demo image](https://prnt.sc/uocym2)

this is my component

```
 constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
        private ngZone: NgZone) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //load Places Autocomplete
        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            this.setCurrentLocation();
            this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

            let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    //get the place result
                    let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

                    //verify result
                    if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    //set latitude, longitude and zoom
                    this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                    this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                    this.zoom = 12;
                });
            });
        });
    }

    // Get Current Location Coordinates
    private setCurrentLocation() {
        if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                this.zoom = 8;
                this.getAddress(this.latitude, this.longitude);
            });
        }
    }
```

this is my view code

```
  <agm-map #gm [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [markerDraggable]="true"
            (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)" (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow,gm)"
            (mouseOut)="onMouseOut(infoWindow, $event)">
            <agm-info-window [isOpen]="false" #infoWindow>
                <a class="btn btn-attention pull-right">
                    Press the Red Location Pin, then move the Pin to your location。
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                </a>
            </agm-info-window>
        </agm-marker>

    </agm-map>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed Map Marker**

You can use normal CSS to achieve this ie:

```
<div class="map">
  <agm-map
 ...
  ></agm-map>
  <div class="map-center-overlay">
    <img src="../assets/marker.svg" width="30" height="30">
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.map {
  position: relative;
}

.map-center-overlay {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

You may also be able to achieve this using `<agm-marker>` but there are some complications using a fixed position, see here: [Can I give an anchor to a marker in agm/core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50479434/1188074)

**Updating lat/long on drag end**

You want to attach to the *map* drag end event, rather than the *marker* (as you will not be dragging the marker).

It seems the `dragEnd` event on the map is not directly exposed(see https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1092) but it can be achieved like:

```
<agm-map
  ...
  (centerChange)="centerChanged($event)"
  (mapReady)="mapReady($event)"
  ></agm-map>    

public centerChanged(coords: LatLngLiteral) {
    this.centerLatitude = coords.lat;
    this.centerLongitude = coords.lng;
  }

public mapReady(map) {
  map.addListener("dragend", () => {
    // do something with centerLatitude/centerLongitude
    });
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

Here is a working stackblitz(view the console to see the lat/long on drag end): https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-agm-map-centre-marker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmap.component.ts

Comment: Working like a charm!