# Show Moving Marker On updated Route (gmaps.js)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

```
var map;
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){      
    updateMap();
    interval = setInterval(updateMap,10000);

    function updateMap() {
        $.ajax({

            url: "gettriproute?trip_id="+{{ $id }}, 

            success: function(result){ 
            if (result.latlong == 'false') {
                //alert('route not found');
                $('#map').empty();
                $('#map').append('<h1 style="text-align: center;">Route not found</h1>');
                return false;
            }

            if (result.status[0] != 'ongoing') {
                $('#map').empty();
                $('#map').append('<h1 style="text-align: center; opacity: 0.5;">Trip Completed</h1>');
                return false;   
            }

            var len = (result.latlong.length) -1;                    
            var center = Math.round(len/2);
            path = result.latlong;


            $($(result.latlong).get().reverse()).each(function(index, element) {                    

            });

            //if (counter == 1) {                    
                map = new GMaps({
                el: '#map',
                //zoom:18,
                lat: result.latlong[len][0],
                lng: result.latlong[len][1],

               });
            //   counter = counter + 1;  
            // }

            map.removeMarkers();
            map.removePolylines();

            map.drawPolyline({
                path: path,
                strokeColor: '#00B9FF',
                strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                strokeWeight: 6
            });

            map.addMarker({
                lat: result.latlong[0][0],
                lng: result.latlong[0][1],
                title: 'Start Point',

            });

            map.addMarker({
                lat: result.latlong[len][0],
                lng: result.latlong[len][1],
                rotation: 90,
                icon:'{{ asset('public/img/marker.png') }}',


            });

            // map.fitZoom({                          
            //     latLngs: result.latlong[len]
            // });

            //ajax request end braces
            },
            error: function(e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

this is my code which update the map with ajax result problem is below described any help thanks in advance

i want to show dynamic moving marker on ajax result but the map zoom in automatically. i just want to focus on end point and move marker smoothly without refreshing the map and also want to rotate car marker as per direction

Answer (score 0):

1. To show the marker movement smoothly and stop re-initializing the map, just initialize it outside the ajax request for the first time and update the marker position using `marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng({lat:"",lng:""}))` instead of removing and re-adding it with new co-ordinates.

[marker.setPosition Google API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/marker#Marker.setPosition)

The smoothness can be achieved via long-polling the request using `setInterval` (as you have implemented) frequently or `WebSockets`. The long-polling requests may not resolve in the given order, as it is made asynchronously. So implement a socket connection and write the co-ordinates as `json` objects from server and update the map using `WebSocket.onMessage` event handler.

2. To change the icon direction, angle needs to be calculated. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800613/rotating-image-marker-image-on-google-map-v3) has the implementation for it (for both V2 and V3).