# Google Maps JS Custom Marker Image

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

So I'm currently using a hack-a-round to rotate custom image marker in google maps.

The problem I'm facing is sizing. Basically if my png image is say 400px wide and 200px height.

When you rotate that image where the width is vertical, it cuts off the image.

How am I suppose to fit the image inside the bounds. Pseudo code I was thinking was something like this at first but couldn't get it to work.

```
const image = currentImage;
if(image.width > image.height){
   //make bounding box of marker image.width squared 
} else{
   //make bounding box of marker image.height squared
}
```

Just for reference this is my rotate function:

```
function rotate() {
const images = $("#map").find("img").get();
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      if ($(images[i]).attr("src").replaceAll(window.location.origin, "") === currentMarker.itemSrc) {
         $(images[i]).css({
             'transform': 'rotate(' + currentDeg + 'deg)',
         });
         break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I add a marker: (don't mind my custom fields I added to the marker object)

```
    const markerIcon = {
        url: currentImage.src + "#" + allMarkers.length,
        // size: new google.maps.Size(?, ?),
        // origin: new google.maps.Point(?, ?),
        // anchor: new google.maps.Point(?, ?)
    };

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        icon: markerIcon,
        itemSrc: currentImage.src.replaceAll(window.location.origin, "") + "#" + allMarkers.length,
        id: lat + "," + lng,
        optimized: false
    });
```

[image: Car rotated vertical]

[image: Car default origin]

Comment: It’s a better idea to just rotate and save your marker image in its png/jpg format before inserting it in Google Maps JavaScript. That way, you don’t have to rotate it in your code implementation.

Comment: Yes that would be best but the user needs the ability to rotate the marker without having to delete it and add it back with that new rotation

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.
This code will increase your marker DIV container and center the image.

Don't worry about the custom field `rotation`. That field doesnt exist for custom image marker. I created it to keep track and update the rotation of the image.

```
const currentImage = whateverYourImageIs;

    let markerSize;
    let origin;
    if(currentImage.naturalWidth > currentImage.naturalHeight){
        markerSize = currentImage.naturalWidth;
        origin = new google.maps.Point(0 , -(markerSize - currentImage.naturalHeight) / 2);
    }else{
        markerSize = currentImage.naturalHeight;
        origin = new google.maps.Point(-(markerSize - currentImage.naturalWidth) / 2 , 0);
    }




function createMarker(position, iconImage, label, rotation, markerSize, origin) {

const markerIcon = {
    url: iconImage,
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(20, 20),
    size: new google.maps.Size(markerSize, markerSize),
    origin: origin,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0)
};

return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    icon: markerIcon,
    optimized: false,
    label: label,
    rotation: rotation
});
}
```